# Invalid cross-thread exception in silverlight

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, silverlight, user-interface

I have a VB silverlight app that is going to be a card game.  I have been trying to get the individual cards (which I create programatically, as Silverlight "Image" controls, wrapped in their own "CardImage" class) to move when moused over.  I want them to kind of "pop up" when the mouse is over them, and then drop back down when the mouse leaves.

Essentially, I'm moving Image.Margin.Top up 5 pixels on mouseenter, and down 5 pixels on mouseleave events.

I have been experiencing that dreaded "unhandled exception" regarding invalid cross-thread access, and having done my homework, I have learned about the UI thread versus the worker thread, etc, and have attempted to put the whole "begininvoke" thing in to practice to become more thread safe.

Here's the problem:  The exception is still happening.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class CardImage

Public Disp As Dispatcher = Deployment.Current.Dispatcher
Public WithEvents Image As New Image

Private Sub MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Image.MouseEnter
    Try
        Invoke(Sub() Image.Margin = New Thickness(Image.Margin.Left, Image.Margin.Top - 5, 0, 0))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Image.MouseLeave
    Try
        Invoke(Sub() Image.Margin = New Thickness(Image.Margin.Left, Image.Margin.Top + 5, 0, 0))
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Invoke(ByVal act As Action)
    If Disp.CheckAccess Then
        act.Invoke()
    Else
        Disp.BeginInvoke(act)
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

The exception is thrown when I move the mouse VERY fast across all the cards that are displayed (as a "hand" of 13 cards across).  Please bear in mind that the players may end up doing this sort of thing... and I really don't want the app crashing because some user with ADHD decides they want the cards to ripple and "do the wave" over and over, while impatiently waiting for other people to play their cards.

Any hints as to why my UI thread is still not taking the thread that's updating the image margins?

Comment: FYI: I have also tried the "image.checkaccess" method, with the recursive call-back.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer was wrong. Since your methods are coming from the Event Handlers, I would think that they would already be on the UI thread, which is why the error still happens. Are you programatically creating the CardImage instances on another thread perhaps?

Comment: @Kratz The Card Images are being created as a result of a button click event firing on the main silverlight page. The button (which is simply a button to "deal" a new test hand) creates all 52 of the CardImage objects, and arranges them.  So you'd think that would ALL be on the UI thread.

Comment: What makes you think `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` are executing on a different thread? They look like the typical UI mouse events to me which means they would already be on the UI thread. Perhaps your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering the same thing... You'd think all of these events would happen together.

Comment: If the mouseenter and mouseleave events are being fired on a UI element, while the UI thread is updating, and has control, why am I getting this exception? @BrianGideon

Comment: @JaredMark: I don't see how those event handles can be executing while the UI is updating. The UI thread can only do one thing at a time...either it's redrawing the UI elements or executing the event handlers. It can't do both at the same time.

Comment: Could you post the whole exception message/stack trace and exactly what part of your code throws the exception? As far as I am aware, if you are not creating worker threads in your code, then everything should be on the UI thread and this error shouldn't happen.

Comment: I'm not multithreading at all.  As far as a stack trace is concerned, that's another problem.  This is throwing an exception that ought to have been caught and processed, but it's asking me to start a new debugger when it happens... I can't seem to get a stack trace of anything out of it.

Comment: @Kratz "An unhandled exception of ('Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 4004
Category: ManagedRuntimeError
Message: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.

This is in the JIT debugger window asking me to launch a new instance of MS VS 2010.  I'm running the app with an F5 out of an already-running Visual Studio instance... and all other exceptions are caught by the attached debugger in IE.  I can't access a stack trace.

Comment: What's worse is... it's not triggering any breakpoints on the "catch" code...

Comment: @JaredMark: If I may state the obvious...you do have an odd problem here.

Comment: @BrianGideon If this isn't the oddest thing... I get the exception when running the app from an F5 in visual studio... but NOT when running the deployment version in firefox directly from the website... outside of the debugger.

Comment: You said it's not triggering breakpoints in the "catch" code, but have you tried setting a breakpoint in the Application_UnhandledException event handler in App.xaml.cs? If it gets hit, you could take a look at e.ExceptionObject to get its stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Image' is created in the context of the thread that creates CardImage. If that's not the UI-Thread but a worker thread you cannot access it from the UI-Thread (to where you dispatched the mouse events.

Create it in the UI-Thread:

```
Public WithEvents Image As Image

Public Sub New()

   Image = Invoke(Function()
                       return New Image
                  End Function)

End Sub

Private Function Invoke(ByVal procedure As Func(of System.Windows.Controls))

    If Disp.CheckAccess Then
       return procedure.Invoke()
    Else
        return Disp.Invoke(procedure)
    End If

End Function
```